# Fatal error Prestashop after change SMARTY.config.inc.php file

Tags: php, templates, compiler-errors, smarty, prestashop

so I use prestashop with smarty and I changed 2 lines in '`..\config\smarty.config.inc.php`' file and now I get these errors.
(I didn't change anything else!)

The lines I changed:

(1) 
original:

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');
```

changed to:

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');
```

(2) 
from

```
$smarty = new SmartyCustom();
```

to:

```
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

I have Product Properties Extension module.

Error front page:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/themes/warehouse/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl"
>   on line 70 "{assign var='icpClass'
>   value=$product|icp:id_cart_product}" unknown modifier "icp" <-- thrown
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 70

Errors backoffice (if I click the message to solve it 'Product Properties Extension: Integration warning. Your site will not work properly until you resolve the integration problems.')

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/modules/pproperties/views/templates/admin/_configure/pproperties/templates.tpl"
>   on line 12 "{l s='Add new' mod='pproperties'}" unknown modifier
>   "pp_safeoutput" <-- thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 12 [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file
>   :/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:
>   Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/modules/pproperties/views/templates/admin/_configure/pproperties/templates.tpl"
>   on line 12 "{l s='Add new' mod='pproperties'}" unknown modifier
>   "pp_safeoutput" <-- thrown

Backoffice popup warning:

> Warning on line 198 in file
>   /var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/modules/gamification/gamification.php [2]
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/MYWEBSITE/modules/gamification/views/css/advice-1.6.1.5_508.css):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I replaced the modified file
with a copy of the original, but it still shows these errors. I delete
the caches but the page still not displayed and the errors still
there.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Revert the edits, and delete the content of this two folders (not the entire folders): `rootofps/cache/smarty/compile/` and `rootofps/cache/smarty/cache`. If you have problem with a module I suggest you to ask to creator of module ;)

Comment: You might find some hints as to what is the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory